# Input a value into an HTML webpage using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv

I am attempting to automate inputting values into a webpage. However, the major issue is that the Mechanize library does not work because my webpage has no forms that Mechanize's `form.name` recognizes. This is due to the input being a <input>.
I have spent the past hour researching alternatives to Mechanize that might work, but to no avail. Google is of no help as it only thinks I want to take data from a website.

My current code:

```html
from mechanize import Browser
import csv

csv_file = 'city_names.csv'  # file name

cities = []  # array to save values from csv into

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cities.append(row.get('cities'))

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
br.open("https://iafisher.com/projects/cities/world")  # The website if you are curious
for form in br.forms():
    print(form.name)  # Prints nothing
for i in range(len(cities)):
    br.select_form(class="city-input")  # ISSUE IS THROWN HERE
    control = br.form.find_control("controlname")
    # Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
    # to the selected HTMLForm (from ClientForm).
    br[control] = [cities[i]]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
    response = br.submit()  # submit current form
```

The input value as seen in developer tools:
`<input data-v-018e983a="" id="city-input" type="text" placeholder="Try 'Tokyo' or 'Kingston, Jamaica'" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="city-input ">`

If there is any alternative to Mechanize or a method in Mechanize that would work, it would be appreciated.

Comment: alternate to mechanize is `selenium`

Comment: I forgot to include that I experimented around with selenium and BeatifulSoup, nothing that I did ended up working. I am quite new to this, so there might be something I missed @Ajay

Comment: There is no form tag in the website you mentioned. Its just a stray text input. That's why the code can't find one.

Comment: @RishabhKumar I explained that in my question, it's why there is a question in the first place. See my answer for how I solved it

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read that. Yes saw your answer. Its similar to what I would do in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple different search options, I finally stumbled across a tutorial that manually tells Selenium what to do.

Final code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

csv_file = 'city_names.csv'

cities = []

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        cities.append(row.get('cities'))

chromedriver_location = "C:/Users/blais/Downloads/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location)
driver.get('https://iafisher.com/projects/cities/world')

submit = '//*[@id="city-input"]'

for c in range(len(cities)):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit).send_keys(cities[c] + Keys.ENTER)
```